# Can I nest a resource which is used elsewhere?

Tags: ember.js

Our app allows orders to be placed, with this unsurprising routing:

```coffee
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "orders", ->
    @route "new"
```

An Order object is associated with a User, unsurprisingly. (Actually, we call them Subscribers, but I'm trying to minimize the internal jargon here.) At the route described above, a new User is created or an existing one is selected from a list:

```coffee
App.OrdersNewRoute   = Em.Route.extend,
  model: ->
    @get("store").createRecord('order', user: @get('store').createRecord('user') )
```

We'd like to be able to create an Order with the User already set, i.e. if we're viewing a user at the route for `/users/1` we could go to `/users/1/orders/new` and have a new Order with `user_id: 1`. So we tried this:

```coffee
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "users", ->
    @route "new"
    @resource "user", path: "/:user_id", ->
      @route "show"
      [...]
      @resource "orders", ->
        @route "new"
```

and this controller:

```coffee
App.UserOrdersNewRoute = Em.Route.extend,
  model: ->
    @get("store").createRecord('order', user: @modelFor('user') )
```

This is not working in an interesting way.

- If we `link_to 'orders.new'` we get sent to the path `/users/undefined/orders/new`.
- If we go to the path `/users/1/orders/new` it uses `OrdersNewController` instead of `UserOrdersNewController`. A new User is being created in the store, as well, so it's not using `UserOrdersNewRoute`.

I made [a fiddle illustrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/A3EPL/).

Am I doing this wrong, or is this just not a practical approach to the problem? **Can I create the same type of resource different ways at different routes?**

Comment: I see- you want to create a new `order`, but if in the user's route already, the new `order` would default the `user` rather than requiring it as an input...  I would like to know the answer to this as well :)  I am therefore deleting my answer...